# A program that will open my html in Safari / Chrome / FF/ IE / Opera

Tags: windows, browser

Does anyone know of any program that allows me to open a html file and it will in turn open that html file in the browsers that I want (Safari / Chrome / FF / IE / Opera) simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making a BAT or CMD file that runs the browsers and provides the "%1" parameter. then associate that BAT or CMD file with the .html file extension.

Update:

For example: file allbrowsers.bat

```
"C:\Apps\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %1
"D:\Apps\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %1
pause
```

Then drag and drop an html file onto allbrowsers.bat using Windows explorer.
Or create a desktop shortcut as a drag & drop target.
Or [associate .html file extensions with allbrowsers.bat](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307859).
Or [Make it an option on your "send to" context menu](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310270)
Or add allbrowsers to the context menu for HTML files (see below)
Or all of the above.

You can add it to the "Open with" context menu as follows ...

- open Windows explorer (not IE!)
- right click an html file
- choose "Open With"
- click "Choose Program"
- click "Browse"
- navigate to allbrowsers.bat
- click "Open"

It will open your html file in all browsers but ALSO add "allbrowsers" to the "Open With" menu.

Comment: arg.. i don't read BAT

Comment: could you help me out..

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: sexy, i could sell this program =D

Comment: btw now the problem i have is that it opens 1 and block, and opens another 1 and block, is there a way we could make it sort of multi-threaded.. so it will open all 5 and just let em run (it's gonna be way faster this way)

Comment: prefix each browser command with `start /B {path to browser} %1`

Comment: it doesn't work for me (for some reason it ends up opening my test file 5 times in google chrome). You can see my code here: http://pastebin.com/BpRU2eMt

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Windows Vista sp2 home premium 32 bit

Comment: Hmm, if you open all the browsers in advance (e.g. to their home page), it works (without the start /B) and each browser opens the page in a new tab or new window. I don't know a better solution.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick are batch commands capable of doing multi-threading ?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, the `start` command normally starts a program and the command shell moves on to the next line in the batch file without waiting for the started program to finish. `start` has a `/WAIT` option if you don't want this behaviour. It may be that in Win7 the `start` command is erroneously applying the "Command Extensions" because of the extension in the parameter (.html) and thus invoking the default program associated with that extension - but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) will allow you to open the HTML file for viewing/editing and, from the "Run" menu, allows you to Launch the file in Firefox, IE, Chrome and Safari.

Comment: ++1 for the Notepad++

Comment: i like the run. however i have to do run 5 times, once for each browser. what i would like to achieve is something like "Run in all 5 now just run!"

Comment: You could try recording a macro in Notepad++ to launch each Browser, then save the Macro against a keyboard shortcut for later use.

Comment: heys do you have an example how would we do that.. i can't really do macros in notepad++

Comment: Notepad++ records the Macro for you - on the Macro menu click Start Recording, then press the key combos to launch each Browser, then click Stop Recording. Now you can Save the Macro for us again later and assign it a key combination for easy launching.